# How can I destroy an empire-level title?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm trying to cause the destruction of an empire-level title (say Byzantine Empire), to create the Latin Empire organically instead of starting with it. As ERE is (still) large, conquering all of it would take enough time, and I already fulfill the other requirements to form the Latin Empire.

What would be an efficient way to destroy the title without too much war effort? One solution I was thinking about is taking away all county-level holdings from the current emperor through wars, but I'm not entirely sure it will work, and it would take some years to get to that point with the current state of affairs.

Will this work? Are other ways to go about it?

Comment: Wouldn't the emperor just revoke some counties from his vassals?

Comment: @svick: not without incurring their displeasure, generally. I'm not sure how AI would react if they run low on holdings, but the penalty for revocation (-20 for counties) is quite severe and would quickly turn all vassals against their liege.

Answer (score 6):

Taking away all county level holdings of the current owner will not work, since he will just claim some from his vassals. You need to take over Every Single Territory owned by him, without taking the title. Once the title does not have any counties under it, directly OR indirectly, it should be destroyed and will allow you to create the latin empire.

Here is one source describing this
http://www.reddit.com/r/CrusaderKings/comments/1azgns/how_to_destroy_the_byzantine_empire/

Unfortunately, this does require a series of wars against what is probably the most powerful empire in the game.

It's also possible to do this using the console commands listed here: http://ckiiwiki.com/Console_commands

Comment: That wouldn't work. The Latin Empire title cannot be created if Byzantine Empire exists. Also, by "destroying" I also mean conditions under which the title would have no holder (which is essentially the same), and for these I don't need to be actually controlling it.

Comment: Please check the new answer, I had forgotten about the issue with creating latin while byzantium exists.

Answer (score -1):

Capture 80% of its de jure counties, usurp the title, destroy the title.

Comment: This only works if you already have an Emperor-level title, as otherwise it would become your primary title and you can't destroy your primary title.